# Troubleshoot webform contributions

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm, contributions, authorize.net

I have a webform, which was working, which collected contributions from users using authorize.net. At the end of the form, users would check the contribution amount, the total would show, and the pieces of the form collecting credit card information would appear. But now, the fields for the credit card info are not appearing and users cannot submit the form. They get the error "credit card information needed."

One possible solution is to upgrade to 4.7, which I can do tomorrow morning, but this was working before with our current configuration. Do you have any troubleshooting tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't update to 4.7! webform_civicrm module is not compatible with 4.7 (yet).

CORRECTION: Looks like the main issue holding that up functionality w/ 4.7 got fixed last month: https://www.drupal.org/node/2661232

Give us some more details - perhaps a URL to the form - so that we can have a look.

Couple of things to check:

1. is the CiviCRM contribution page still working? Does it have the correct Payment Processor still attached? That's where webform_civicrm gets the Payment fields from.
2. By default webform_civicrm will put the $amount total and payment fields on the next page - I'm not 100% sure but I think that may be required for it to load the payment fields.
3. Having different pages (page breaks) in your webform makes for a nice form. I often go: Parents, Children, Waivers, Payment

Example:
[image]

Comment: Good to know! I won't update then. What can I tell you about the configuration that might help you? Here's the url: https://makomcommunity.org/EnrollmentFall2016

Comment: What is the webform_civicrm module version? What version of civicrm are you using?

Comment: CiviCRM 4.6.10, Webform 7.x-4.12, and Webform CiviCRM Integration 7.x-4.15.

Comment: I'll have a look

Comment: Is there a useful summary anywhere of known webform-civicrm issues on 4.7.x?

Comment: Hey Pete -> Coleman tends to link to this URL re: 4.7: https://www.drupal.org/node/2661232

Comment: Hi Naomi - I've added some things to check for you along with a screenshot - hopefully this will help you out!

Comment: Thank you for all your help @KarinG! It appears that your very first question, whether the contribution page was working, was the issue! I will also take your suggestion about page breaks, that is a good idea.

Comment: Excellent - glad you solved it!